# Perfect squares of the form $ab^n+c$ and a Diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, recreational-mathematics

The motivation for this question comes from the following problem from an international Team selection test of 2007 from Chile:

> **Problem:** Let $p$ be a prime number. Find all pairs of positive integers $m,n$ that satisfy the following equation
>   $$(p-1)(p^n-1)=4m(m+1)$$

I have tried a lot to solve this problem and proposed it in other webpages and I have never seen a solution. Hence, I think maybe the jury who made the exam put an intractable/open problem without realize it.

Notice that the equation in the problem has a solution iff the discriminant (as a quadratic equation in $m$) is a perfect square. This led to study the equation $$(p-1)p^n-(p-2)=x^2.\tag{$*$}$$

So my first question is

**Question 1:** Given $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there any systematic study of the Diophantine equation
$$ab^n+c=x^2$$
maybe for some particular choice of $a,b,c$?.

By looking mod $p$ equation ($*$) and using quadratic reciprocity one can show that $p$ should be $\pm 1 \text{ mod } 8$ but I am not sure how much one can say.

So let's take a particular example of a difficult prime for this equation, say $p=23$:

**Question 2:** Does the equation $$22\cdot 23^n-21=x^2$$ has an integral solution for $n>1$?

If someone solve the original problem would great, but an heuristic that it may be open (based in an answer of question 1 for example) would leave me satisfied.

As this may be approached by comparing two ideal factorizations in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{-c})}$ I will put the tag for algebraic number theory.

Comment: Cross-posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314144/perfect-squares-of-the-form-abnc-and-a-diophantine-equation

Comment: The equation $22\cdot23^n-21=x^2$ reduces, in the case $n$ even, to the pair of equations $22y^2-21=x^2$, $y=23^m$, and in the case $n$ odd, to the pair $22\cdot23y^2-21=x^2$, $y=23^m$. So an approach is to solve the Pellians, and then see about the $23^m$ part.